# Is there a canonical list of all domain-level metadata that a site should include?

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt

It's pretty straightforward to remember to create a Google sitemap, a robots.txt file, and maybe a humans.txt file, but are there other similar files which should be created?

[Edit: Other similar files might include crossdomain.xml, favicon.ico, apple-touch-icon]

Answer (score 0):

In wikipedia, you see similar examples of included metadata with the [robots.txt article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt#See_also). As far as file inclusions, it doesn't mention anything further than robots.txt, humans.txt, and sitemap, of which you have already mentioned. It does link to [meta elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element) which will allow for inclusion of meta data within HTML pages.

I've also heard reference to hackers.txt files as an attempt to include warnings to hackers who may attempt to break into your site, but I rarely see that one anymore.